# Where does compiz log error messages?

Tags: compiz, logging

I'm having some trouble with compiz and dual monitors (see [Why won't visual effects work with a dual monitor setup](https://askubuntu.com/q/15608/177)), and I'd like to check the compiz logfiles to see what, if anything, might be happening to cause it to stop working, but I'm not sure where compiz logs its error messages to.

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/Xorg.0.log?

Comment: Hi @Pavlos G., unfortunately, for me `grep compiz /var/log/Xorg.0.log` does not return anything...

Comment: My Ubuntu doesn't have any `/var/log/X*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been unable to find on the net anything related to a real log, only comments like "[Do you get any error messages when you start compiz from the console?](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=182347)"; (see also [Troubleshooting#Checking for problems - Compiz Wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/Troubleshooting#Checking_for_problems)).

My guess is that, if one wants error / warning messages from `compiz` - one has to 'kill' the `compiz` currently running in the background; and then start a new one which will run in the foreground - which can be achieved usually with a single

```
compiz --replace ccp
```

Since the above command is not started with a '`&`', it will thus run in foreground (not run as background process), and it will thus spit error /warning messages to stdout/err..

Note that "[The ccp plugin is required for Compiz to interact with settings made in ccsm](http://wiki.compiz.org/Troubleshooting#Is_Compiz_Running.3F)"

Hope this is not way off, :)
Cheers!