# Need help installing/updating graphics card

Tags: graphics

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my ASUS Ultrabook S56C. After installing it was running great for a few days and then it started to freeze on me. I'm not sure on how to install and update my graphics card because I believe that's what the problem is. I would watch youtube videos and it would get really pixilated and slow. Even when I would try and minimize firefox and terminal it would freeze. can someone give me suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Identify your hardware and update your question, try k/x/lubuntu.

Comment: You can get your hardware info by typing "sudo lshw -html > /home/YOURUSERNAME/hardware.html" and then once it finishes type "firefox /home/YOURUSERNAME/hardware.html" in your terminal. Your display information will be far down the list, after all the cpu/ram entries.

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to System Settings > Software & updates > Additional Drives. You can change the graphics driver there. Try another one or updating the actual one. 
If it doesn't help, I'm not sure if the problem would be on the graphics card (since it worked fine for a few days)

Comment: i tried all the options but still seems to freeze. I'm going to re-install Ubuntu and see if that will fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't not try reinstalling then first try resetting compiz and unity

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools    
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/       
unity-reset
setsid unity
```

If it didn't work then try to reinstall unity

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

If you think it's driver related one then post your video card details and [compiz errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15612/where-does-compiz-log-error-messages). I switched to Gnome myself because of these freezing problems which is because of the bad compiz!